# Make switches in listview checked according to its status saved in shared preferences

Tags: android

My application contains 4 switches in listview.I saved the status of switches in shared preference and able to retrieve the status.I dont know how to enable the switches according to value stored in shared preference with respect to the corresponding position.Anyone please suggest me a method?

Comment: When you save the status, save it like: `filename0`(where 0 is the ID for the order in the ListView). So: `"filename" + IdOfListEntryInListView`

Comment: sorry i didnt understand

Comment: Considering a ListView with 10 entries. You can get the first entry by getting the object with ID 0. So when you save, get the ID of the ListView entry you are trying to save the data from, and save whatever data you need. When you load, create however many entries into the Listview you need, and load the corresponding file using a fixed preset(e.g. "filename") and add the ID.

Comment: I have given positions to switch by setTag and getTag.Is there any way to enable switches with this positions

Comment: [See this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html). Each of the ListItems have its own ID(using "position" in a listener(e.g. onListItemClicked). Get the ID, save the state of the switch in a file using a prefix(e.g. "filename") and finish with the ID. Then load using the same prefix and the ID's(0-x) and load it and set the state of the switches based on the input. Did that make sense?